# Is there a standard tool to trim cache directories?

Tags: linux, files, disk-space-utilization

I want to run a cron job that removes old entries in a cache directory, so that its total size is reduced to a certain amount of bytes. I've concocted this one line shell command, but I was wondering: is there a standard Linux tool (like logrotate for rotating logs) that does the same?

The oneliner is as follows:

```
find /some/cache/dir -type f -printf "%T@ %s %p\n" | sort -rn | awk '{ s += $2 ; if (s > 100000) print $3 }' | xargs rm
```

I use find to gather the timestamp, filesize and filepath of each file. I then sort by timestamp, newest files first. I then calculate the cumulative filesize, outputting files only once a certain limit has been reached. The outputted files are then deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a "standard" way to do this - because there is no "standard" when it comes to how applications cache content: duration, total space used, etc is all dependent upon the specific caching methodologies of the given tool.

What happens when you "trim" something that is currently in use? Just because something was cached a while ago doesn't mean it's not still being handed-out ... and it easily could be being handed-out *while* you are trying to delete it - and that's bad juju all around.

In the overwhelming majority of cases, you should use the app's configuration manager (be it config file, db, etc) to manage its own caching strategy.

I can name one product at least where the file *names* cached have absolutely no correlation to the *files* themselves: and just because it was cached a month ago does *not* mean it isn't still in active use, because the app doesn't update timestamps on cached files - ever. It tracks least-recently-accessed inside itself, and the way to manage cache size is to limit the partition/mount point where the cache is housed (as it will use up to and including the entire space available in its cache directory).

Don't edit application's caches unless you *really* know what will happen when you do.

Comment: My cache trimming job is intended for an application that I'm maintaining myself, so there is no configuration to be managed :)

My take-away is that cache trimming should be part of the code base of the application, not a oneliner in the crontab.

Comment: @ScatoEggen :: don't put it external to the app, no :)